# convert multidimensional array element to integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dimensional array which contain element in format `Name,Number`. i want to convert `Number` part to integer

```
var iTicketTypeCount = [];

var sTicketTypeCount = saResponse[5].split(',');

while (sTicketTypeCount[0]) {
     iTicketTypeCount.push(sTicketTypeCount.splice(0, 2));
}
```

My iTicketTypeCount contains

```
[['Firefox',   '45'],['IE',       '26'],['Safari',    '5'],['Opera',     '6'],['Others',   '7']]
```

and i want it like

```
[['Firefox',   45],['IE',       26],['Safari',    5],['Opera',     6],['Others',   7]]
```

**Only the second element should get converted into integer.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest *imo* would be using **[`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```
var arr = [['Firefox', '45'],['IE', '26'],['Safari', '5'],['Opera', '6'],['Others', '7']];

arr = arr.map(function(x) {
    return [x[0], Number(x[1])];
});
```

Comment: Not that performance is likely to be a concern here, but I'm curious about the advantages of `map` versus iterating and parsing. Is the mapped function called each time that element is accessed, or is its result stored?

Comment: `map()` simply gives you a chance to process each element in an array conveniently. The plus is that this iteration is done in native code - unlike a loop we write.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `parseInt` function to simply convert this:

```
$.each(arry, function(i, elem) {
    arry[i] = [elem[0], parseInt(elem[1])];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var iTicketTypeCount = [];

var sTicketTypeCount = saResponse[5].split(',');

while (sTicketTypeCount[0]) {
     sTicketTypeCount[1] = Number(sTicketTypeCount[1]);
     iTicketTypeCount.push(sTicketTypeCount.splice(0, 2));
}
```

You could do it without using another function.

Answer (score 1):

Try $.each()

```
var arr = [['Firefox',   '45'],['IE',       '26'],['Safari',    '5'],['Opera',     '6'],['Others',   '7']]

$.each(arr, function(idx, value){
    value[1] = +value[1]
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LfdYb/)